# Get values of selected tr in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I have a table and it contains data with checkboxes in each row. When any of the checkboxes is checked, I add the`Selected` class to the corresponding `tr` element.

```
$('#InventoryTable tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) { /** logic */ });
```

But I am facing the issue below, when getting the selected `tr` element on button click.

This is the code I am using to get the seletced `tr` values:

```
function myFunc() {
    debugger;

    var table = $('#InventoryTable').DataTable();
    var adjustmentdetails = new Array();
    $("#InventoryTable tr.selected").each(function (ix, element) {

        // Do your processing.
         debugger;
    });
}
```

However, I am not able to get other page(Pagination) selected values using above code.

Comment: please show your HTML

Comment: **"But am not able to get other page selected values using above code."** What do you mean?

Comment: am using pagination concept for the table. When i selected rows in other page, those values are not coming using above function.

Comment: @DanielH edited my question. please review.

Comment: I have improved the language and formatting of your post to make it more readable. However, you should make clearer what your actual problem is. I do not understand what you mean by "I am not able to get other page selected values using above code". What other page are you talking about? Include further code and maybe a screenshot, to explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

just convert this code into function

```
function clickcheck(e){
  { //logic });
}
```

and apply this function on your checkbox onclick attr and pass event on this function

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it, I assume the add class function is working for you, then use a button on click get all element with type=checkbox and it is input element with class `selected`. then print this value (put your logic here)

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(e) {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
  }
});

$('#getAllCheckedValue').on('click', function() {
  console.log('----------- getAllCheckedValue ----------------');
  $("input.selected[type=checkbox]").each(function(ix, element) {
    console.log('Checked-->' + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="InventoryTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      1<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="test test2">
    </tr>
    <tr>
      2<input type="checkbox" value="2">
    </tr>
    <tr>
      3<input type="checkbox" value="3">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button id="getAllCheckedValue">
  Get All Checked Value
</button>
```

Comment: Daniel, your code will help when checkboxes are in the same page in a table. But for me i need to get all checkbox values in different pages.

Comment: @ManojKumarYellapragada load those page and hide them, then call this function?

Comment: @ManojKumarYellapragada without load all pages into one, I don't think you can use jQuery because it is front end, unless you can make ajax call on each page send data to server so you can have a collection of data